# Nativescript - How do I properly use placeholder property from ui/image-cache to make it work?

Tags: ios, nativescript

I'm trying to create a list view with a set of remote images and while they are loading to display a placeholder image.

```js
var imageSource = require("image-source");
var imageCache = require("ui/image-cache");
var cache = new imageCache.Cache();
var defaultImageSource = imageSource.fromResource("img-loading”);

cache.enableDownload();
cache.placeholder = defaultImageSource;
cache.maxRequests = 5;
```

Tried with fromFile as well instead of fromResource.

Any toughts?

Comment: What doesn't work?

Comment: Well, I'm expecting to see a placeholder/the resource image that I've specified while the remote image loads and that does not happen :)

Comment: @Cosmin I've also got this issue. No matter what I stick in there, whether it's from my resources or a URL it doesn't work. Nothing is displayed at all. I'd recommend opening an issue on the GitHub repo for Nativescript which is found here: https://github.com/Nativescript/nativescript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure how are you using the `ImageCache` but you cannot directly set an `ImageCache` object as source of an `Image`. In order to achieve what you want you must use something like this (taken from http://pstaev.blogspot.com/2016/04/using-nativescripts-imagecache-to-cache.html):

main-page.xml

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" 
      navigatingTo="navigatingTo">
    <ListView items="{{ images }}">
      <ListView.itemTemplate>
        <GridLayout>
          <Image src="{{ imageSrc }}" stretch="aspectFill" height="100"/>
        </GridLayout>
      </ListView.itemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Page>
```

main-page.ts

```
import observableArray = require("data/observable-array");
import observable = require("data/observable");
import imageItem = require("./image-item");
import pages = require("ui/page");

export function navigatingTo(args: pages.NavigatedData)
{
    var page = <pages.Page>args.object;
    var model = new observable.Observable();
    var images = new observableArray.ObservableArray<imageItem.ImageItem>();

    images.push(new imageItem.ImageItem("http://foo.com/bar1.jpg"));
    images.push(new imageItem.ImageItem("http://foo.com/bar2.jpg"));
    // ...
    images.push(new imageItem.ImageItem("http://foo.com/bar100.jpg"));

    model.set("images", images);
    page.bindingContext = model;
}
```

image-item.ts

```
import observable = require("data/observable");
import imageCache = require("ui/image-cache");
import imageSource = require("image-source");

var cache = new imageCache.Cache();
cache.maxRequests = 10;
cache.placeholder = imageSource.fromResource("img-loading")

export class ImageItem extends observable.Observable
{
    private _imageSrc: string
    get imageSrc(): imageSource.ImageSource
    {
        var image = cache.get(this._imageSrc); 

        if (image)
        {
            return image;
        }

        cache.push(
            {
                key: this._imageSrc
                , url: this._imageSrc
                , completed:
                (image) =>
                {
                    this.notify(
                        {
                            object: this
                            , eventName: observable.Observable.propertyChangeEvent
                            , propertyName: "imageSrc"
                            , value: image
                        });
                }
            });

        return cache.placeholder;
    }

    constructor(imageSrc : string)
    {
        super();
        this._imageSrc = imageSrc;
    }
}
```