# Using image-cache for a LIstView in Typescript/Angular2/Nativescript

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I've implemented a solution similar to this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36388811/690293) however I'm using Angular2 conventions to define my page and not traditional Nativescript as in the referenced discussion.

The issue is that my ListView does not react to the `notifyPropertyChange` event to update the images when the upload into the image-cache is complete. The displayed images do not change from the placeholder image until I force it to update such as scrolling to hide the row and it updates when it reappears or leave the page and return.

I'm thinking the problem is that I'm mixing `data/observable` and the `Angular2 Observable` and/or the `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`.  Suggestions?

Definition of ImageItem

```
    import observable = require("data/observable");
    import imageCache = require("ui/image-cache");
    import imageSource = require("image-source");
    import {Config, everliveConfig } from './config';

    var cache = new imageCache.Cache();
    cache.maxRequests = 10;
    cache.placeholder = imageSource.fromFile("~/resource-seed/butterfly.jpg");

    export class ImageItem extends observable.Observable
    {
        private _imageSrc: string
        get imageSrc(): imageSource.ImageSource
        {
            var image = cache.get(this._imageSrc); 

            if (image)
            {
                return image; /* 3 */
            }

            cache.push(
                {
                    key: this._imageSrc,
                    url: this._imageSrc,
                    completed: (image) =>
                    {
                        this.notifyPropertyChange('imageSrc', image);
                        console.log("this.notifyPropertyChange('imageSrc', image)");
                    }
                });

            return cache.placeholder; 
        }

        constructor(imageId : string)
        {
            super();

            everliveConfig.files.getDownloadUrlById(imageId)
                .then( url => {
                    this._imageSrc = url;
                });
        }
    }
```

Layout of my component

```
<GridLayout rows="32, 32, *" columns="*">
    <Label row="0" text='Points of Interest'   class='page-title'    horizontalAlignment="center" > </Label>
    <Label row="1" text='Tap to learn more'  class='page-subtitle' horizontalAlignment="center" > </Label>
    <ListView row="2" [items]="areas" class="area-group" (itemTap)="onItemTap($event)">
        <template let-area="item">
            <GridLayout rows="100" columns="38, 100, *" orientation="horizontal">
                <Button col="0" [backgroundImage]='checkButtonImagePath(area)' 
                    class='area-checkmark-button'
                    (tap)='onToggleCheck(area)'>
                </Button>
                <Image col="1" [src]='area.imageItem.imageSrc' class='area-thumbnail' stretch="aspectFill"></Image>
                <Label col="2" [text]='area.Name' class='area-title'>  </Label>
            </GridLayout>
        </template>
   </ListView> 
</GridLayout>
```

Component Definition

```
import { Component, ChangeDetectionStrategy, Inject }  from "@angular/core";
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Area, AreaList } from '../../shared/model/area.list';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: "area",
    templateUrl: "area.html",
    styleUrls:["area.common.css"],
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class AreaComponent {

   public areas ;

    constructor(
        private _router: Router,
         @Inject('AreaList') public areaList: AreaList) {
           this.areas = areaList.list;
        }

    public onItemTap(args) {
        console.log("Item Tapped at cell index: " + args.index);
        var area: Area = this.areaList.area(args.index);
        this._router.navigate(["/detail", area.Key]);
    }

    public onToggleCheck(area:Area) {
        area.isChecked = !area.isChecked;
    }

    public checkButtonImagePath(area):string {
        return area.isChecked ? 'res://dawes_11' : 'res://dawes_21';
    }

}
```

Definition of AreaList

```
import {Config, everliveConfig } from './config';
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import {ImageItem} from '../../shared/model/image.item';
import { ObservableArray } from "data/observable-array";

export class Area {
    public isChecked = false;
    public imageItem : ImageItem;
    constructor(
        public Id: string,
        public Name: string,
        public Description: string,
        public Image: string,
        public Key: string
        ) {
            this.imageItem = new ImageItem(this.Image);
        }
}
@Injectable()
export class AreaList  {
    public list : Array<Area>;
    constructor () {
        var areaData = everliveConfig.data('Area');
        areaData.get(null, data => {
            var l = new Array<Area>();
            data.result.forEach(area => {
                    l.push(new Area(area.Id, area.Name, area.Description,
                        area.Image, area.Key))
            })
            this.list = l; 
        },
        err => {
            console.log(err.message);
        });
    }

    public area(index: number) : Area {
        return this.list[index];
    }

    public areaByKey(key: string) : Area {
        for (let area of this.list) {
            if (key == area.Key) {
                return area;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: image-cache is not applicable for N+Angular-2 projects. In NativeScript 2.4.0 image-asset was introduced and this module is optimized for performance. You can also use nativescript-fresco for Android implementatioons.

Comment: @NickIliev can you point me to an example on how to use image-asset.

Comment: @ahalls did you find any info/examples of ns/ng2 using image-asset. Not much documentation on this, that I can find.

Comment: @LarryKing Agreed I couldn't find documentation, blog or example code.  I did find another plugin, nativescript-web-image-cache.  It is built on  SDWebImageCache library for IOS and Facebook Fresco for android.  Has the minimal bit of documentation a nativescript plugin.  Working better then image-cache in that it is not crashing on Android. Haven't done any performance testing.   https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-web-image-cache https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-web-image-cache